# Title for a person one has had children with

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, kinship-terms

I'm looking for a word meaning "Someone X has had children with".

> Joseph really gets around. He's had 15 girlfriends, and 2 [] so far

Or

> Martha has 3 children, but has had them with two []

Comment: Biological mother/father could fit in your second example, but it won't fit in your first example. What is your question?

Comment: The questioner appears to be looking for a single word or phrase that may not exist, other than in a very colloquial or figurative way.  In the first instance, consider adding something on the order of "by who he has fathered two children so far,.  In the second, the brackets could enclose "different men."  *Promiscuous* seems to cover the whole business...

Comment: Genitors, fecundators or inseminator  could fit the second one. You could also bring genetrix back from the semantic grave if the genitors were females.

Comment: Married or unmarried?

Comment: @Gandalf Hopefully for both (ie doesn't matter)

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially, you might go with **baby mama** or **baby daddy**.

Shockingly, there is a wikipedia entry on [baby mama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_mama):

> A baby mama (also baby-mama and baby-mother) is a mother who is not married to her child's father, although the term is often infused with other meanings as well.

At best this is slang, so it might not be appropriate for all contexts.

Comment: NB: "baby mama" and "baby daddy" may have significantly negative connotations.  Use with great care.

Comment: @Rob_Ster I don't disagree, but it also depends on the context. What does NB mean?

Comment: NB is a latinate abbreviation commonly found in academic and other formal documents.  It means "Nota Bene," or (note well...it's important to note that...yeah, but...etc.)

Comment: @Rob_Ster Cool, thanks! I've never seen that before.

Comment: @Rob_Ster: I think you may be on a euphemism treadmill here: it might not be that "baby parent" has negative connotations but that bastardy itself has negative connotations and so whatever phrase used to denote it will carry the connotations.